# MySQL JOIN & Split String

Tags: string, mysql, join

I want to JOIN two table. Have no problem with that. I have problem with quite different thing.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2` ON `table1.`field`=`table2`.`field`
...
```

The main issue is that `table1.field` is a string, comma-separated. Is there any good and fast way to split it?

**Update**
I found a function by Federico Cagnelutti

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Usage:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('a|bb|ccc|dd', '|', 3) as third;
```

Quite useful but it requires position integer as third parameter. Anyway, I **do not** know the amount of comma-separated words. Bascially, it's up to 20 words, but I don't know how many.

**Update 2**
To clarify my question. Here's what I like to have (I know the following query is incorrect):

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`id` IN (`table1`.`field`)
```

**Update 3**
Example strings: `table1.field` = '202, 185, 505', `table2.field` = 202

Comment: Can you give an example of the string that you are mentioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you need, but perhaps you could use the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function?

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2` ON FIND_IN_SET( `table2`.`field`, `table1.`field` ) > 0
```

Performance might be a problem with this though.

*Update:*

If you have leading spaces in the data, as in the sample given, this could be handled with [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).  This wouldn't work where there are embedded spaces, but would cater for cases where there are sometimes leading spaces and sometimes not.  Example:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
JOIN    table2 t2
ON      FIND_IN_SET( t2.field, REPLACE( t1.field, ' ', '' ) ) > 0
```

There is a [limit of 64 members in a set](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html), so if the comma-separated string is long this will break.

Comment: I tried it before and it returns only first `table2.field` value. Does my question need any clarification?

Comment: Currently I solved this issue with REGEXP, wondering if this is a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: @Tom - if REGEXP works, it works!  Take care that you don't get false matches, for example '%85%' would match sample data in your question unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! I checked it on 20k records and found no bug. Also works really fast. On MySQL Forums I was adviced to to normalize my data and to not store categories as comma-separated values. But...from the other hands, it will cause a lot more queries, that's why I decided to go this way. Anyway, thanks! Your answer let me find solution for REGEXP so I'm gonna mark it as correct answer (while looking for solution to use FIND_IN_SET, I found REGEXP). Thanks for your time and your advices. Tom.